# SpiderMonkey for JavaScript and WebKit for everything else?

Tags: browser, webkit, spidermonkey

Is that possible to run SpiderMonkey for JavaScript and WebKit for everything else (CSS, rendering etc)?

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28ECMAScript%29 WebKit have obsolete JS support (compared to Gecko). So can it work?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, nobody has done the legwork to integrate the SpiderMonkey engine into the WebKit code base, but JSC (the WebKit JavaScript implementation) is also a quality, standards-conforming JavaScript engine implementation. There was some work on putting a V8 API on SpiderMonkey, which has some promise for integrating SpiderMonkey into the Chromium code base I suppose, but I don't know how active that effort currently is.